# git rebase commit by commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a branch of 10 commits. Now master changed and I want to rebase my branch to the new master's HEAD. However, some of the new master commits make even the first commit of my branch uncompilable (without merge conflicts). Rebasing a branch seems pointless to me if all of your commits are not compilable in the end.

What I'd like to do is tell get "do a rebase, but wait after rebasing of each commits from my branch". That way, I can detect if the code still compiles after each commit, make it compile (if required), and then commit and continue.

Is this possible? Are there alternatives for a clean rebase, such that each commit will still compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

The simplest method is probably to use `git rebase -i` and change each `pick` to `edit`.  After Git does each of the cherry-pick operations, it will drop back to the command line.  You can now attempt the build (and run tests) and when something fails, fix it up.  Once everything is good, run `git add -u` and `git commit --amend` as appropriate, then `git rebase --continue` to apply the next commit in sequence.

After you've become familiar with this method (don't start with this right away!) consider using `--exec` as well, if your Git supports it.

**Note:** if a commit to be copied—regardless of whether it is marked `pick` or `edit`—has a merge conflict, `git rebase` stops with that merge conflict.  Even if you did mark it `edit`, Git won't stop *again* after resolving the conflict, so if you must resolve something as well as change something else, you should do both at once here (and do not use `git commit --amend` as you are still making the *first* copy).

#### Long details in case you're interested / curious

It's physically impossible for Git to alter any existing commit, because the true name of each commit—its hash ID—is a cryptographic checksum of all of the *contents* of that commit, including your name as author/committer, the time stamp, and of course all of the source code that goes with the snapshot.

It is, however, easy enough for Git to *copy* a commit—well, as long as it's an ordinary non-merge commit, with a single parent.  Given some commit whose hash ID is *H*, Git can turn *H*, which is a snapshot, into a change-set against *H*'s parent.  Think of this as what `git show` does: it extracts the parent's snapshot, then extracts the commit's snapshot, and whatever is different between them (`git diff <parent-of-H> <H>`), that's what *changed*.  One can then apply these same changes to some *other* commit, by checking out that *other* commit, and then commit the result.  That is, if we have two branches `branch1` and `branch2`, we can check out the tip commit of the second branch and create a new, temporary branch:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch1
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2, temp (HEAD)
```

We then turn commit `H` into a change-set, apply the change-set to commit `L`, and make a new commit that has a new and different hash ID.  This new commit is so much like `H` that we call it `H'` for illustration:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch1
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2
           \
            H'  <-- temp (HEAD)
```

This copy operation is a `git cherry-pick`.  (Technically each cherry-pick operation is a full three-way merge, rather than just applying a change-set-style patch, but we don't need to worry about this unless and until various complications occur.)

If we *repeat* the cherry-picking for all the commits that were on `branch1` we get this:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch1
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2
           \
            H'-I'-J'  <-- temp (HEAD)
```

and if we now "peel the label" `branch1` off `J` and attach it to `J'` instead, discarding the temporary name entirely, we end up with:

```
...--G--H--I--J   [abandoned]
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2
           \
            H'-I'-J'  <-- branch1 (HEAD)
```

Rebasing is therefore really a series of cherry-pick operations.  An *interactive* rebase make this explicit: each commit hash ID turns into a `pick` command in a script.

Changing the `pick` to `edit` tells Git that after doing each of the various cherry-pick steps, it should stop and return to the command line.  (Note that Git *also* stops and returns to the command line, all on its own, if there is a merge conflict.)  Running `git rebase --continue` tells Git to consult the control files that this leaves behind—these are managed by something Git internally calls the *sequencer*—to see what other commit(s) still need whatever sort of handling.  Hence if you mark every commit as "to be edited", Git stops after copying `H` to `H'`, so that you have this:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch1
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2
           \
            H'  <-- HEAD
```

(I've updated the drawing to rely on the way Git really does this: rather than attempting to invent a temporary branch name, Git uses "detached HEAD" mode to do the copying.)

At this point, if you make changes and run `git add -u && git commit --amend`, Git makes yet another new commit—let's call this H-prime-prime or `H"`—whose parent is the same as `H'`'s parent:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch1
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2
          |\
          | H'  [abandoned]
           \
            H"  <-- HEAD
```

When you now run `git rebase --continue`, Git cherry-picks commit `I` to `I'` appended to `H"`, and then—because you said "edit"—stops yet again:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- branch1
      \
       K--L   <-- branch2
          |\
          | H'  [abandoned]
           \
            H"-I'  <-- HEAD
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. I'm guessing you use `-u` in `git add -u` as it's more careful than `-a`, and since you would not expect adding/removing files when fixing a rebase?

Comment: Yes, generally `-u` tends to be the right thing here. Any options or parameters that achieve the desired index updates is fine, of course.

Comment: I just tried it out, but the amend did not work. What I did was a `git rebase -i`, setting all to "edit", and when it stopped after the first merge, I did manual changes. Then, I did git `commit --amend`, which modified the tip of the *master* branch (or better, I think it created a new commit there). Must I somehow commit before the amend?

Comment: Once you select `edit` and let rebase run and then halt, `git status` should show that you are not on *any* branch: you should have `HEAD detached at ...` or `HEAD detached from ...` (the exact string depends on your Git version). The `--amend` should therefore update the detached HEAD, after which `git rebase --continue` should continue cherry-picking atop the latest commit.

Comment: It does not directly say "detached", but "[rebase in progress](https://bpaste.net/show/5886db92de36)". I made [screenshots of gitk](https://imgur.com/a/gJhyU1E).

Comment: Ah, right, even-newer Git versions use eg `interactive rebase in progress; onto e1cc28b`. But certainly after it stops, you should be able to modify files in the work tree, add them (`git add` with whatever options), and `git commit --amend` to edit the commit message already copied after the paused cherry-pick. I just tested this on a simple repo I made and it works OK for me...

Comment: While it worked on my desktop with a minimal example, too, the following reconstructs the situation where I don't get it working: https://bpaste.net/show/977c77a96e89 . If you execute those commands, at least for me, the amend changes the *master top commit* , not the first commit of the branch "osc-plugin". Can you please check if it works for you?

Comment: OK, this is interesting. Submodules and added work-trees can change some things. However, when I run your script, after the `git fetch fork osc-plugin` the `git worktree add ../osc-plugin osc-plugin` fails because there's no local `osc-plugin` (just `fork/osc-plugin`). I manually did `git worktree add ../osc-plugin fork/osc-plugin` instead (and chdir-ed), did the second submodule init, and ran `git status`: "Not currently on any branch." This status is due to using `fork/osc-branch`. If I fix it with `git checkout -b osc-branch` and start the rebase...

Comment: ... it starts OK, and I'm in another detached HEAD with a conflict on `src/gui/FileBrowser.cpp`. Manually resolving and committing (with or without `--amend`) seems to work OK, etc. The whole thing about starting from a detached HEAD is probably the source of the problem.

Comment: So it did not overwrite master's top commit for you? Can you please paste the history of commands you used, so I can try it?

Comment: It's impossible for Git to *overwrite* a commit, the only thing it can do is create a *new* commit and update some name. If you start with a detached HEAD it will overwrite the detached HEAD. If your Git is somehow starting with HEAD naming `master`, it would overwrite the *name* `master`. (Picky wording but it matters!) I used your script up to the point where it failed (`git worktree add` failed, and then the `cd` also failed since the added work-tree did not exist). I then used the `git worktree add` shown above, followed by `git checkout -b osc-branch` as shown above.

Comment: I made [another test](https://gist.github.com/JohannesLorenz/debb291fae98455657e720ab293eb678). It looks like git behaves differently if there's a merge conflict: It does not stop after you made the "rebase --continue" and does not allow you to do changes afterwards ("commit --amend" is wrong in this case). Can you please confirm that? If yes, it might be good to add this to your answer.

Comment: Aha! Yes, if Git has already stopped due to a merge conflict, it considers that sufficient for the "edit" case. Note that Git has not yet made the copy-of-the-original commit, so in the general case (in between various other edits) you don't want to use `git commit --amend` here: just resolve all conflicts and get the commit into shape, then `git rebase --continue` to move to the next commit.

Answer (score 1):

The `edit` option when you are doing an interactive rebase allow you to pause on the commit, use `git commit --amend` to add any modification to the commit, and then continue to the next one with `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, **I recommend `cherry-pick`ing, instead of `rebase`**.

---

For example if you want to `rebase` the branch `feature` on `main`:

1. Create branch `feature2` on `main` and `checkout` on it.
2. `cherry-pick` commits of `feature` onto `feature2` **one-by-one**.
3. `checkout` on `feature` and `reset` it (`--keep` or `--hard`) to `feature2`.
4. Delete `feature2`.